# Make script answer "Y" to prompts from apt-get

Tags: shell-script, apt

I use a `bash` script to initially set up and update virtual machines. Trying to make this `bash` script configure the VMs without having to do so manually.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
  
echo "Updating and Installing binaries"
echo yes | sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I'm not sure how to automatically reply `Y` to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` "Do you want to continue?" prompt. How can I fix my script to do so?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option `-y` to `apt-get` will automatically answer "yes" to prompts. This also causes `apt-get` to run non-interactively. If a held package were to be changed, an unauthenticated package would be installed, or an essential package would be uninstalled, then `apt-get` will abort its operation.

The `--yes` and `--assume-yes` options are aliases of `-y`.

This means you could write your script like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
  
echo 'Updating and Installing binaries'
sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

or, if you assume that the script is being executed by root (this avoids interactively being asked for passwords by `sudo` while the script is running):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo 'Need to be root' >&2
    exit 1
fi

apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
```

The `--trivial-only` option could be considered the logical opposite of `--assume-yes`, in that it would answer "no" to any prompt.

Further information about `apt-get` is found in its manual (`man apt-get`).

Comment: I think the general advice is to _not_ use sudo in a script, but instead launch it with `sudo sh myscript`, so prefer the 2nd example.

Comment: If the script is specifically a `bash` script, then the id check can be `if ((EUID != 0))`

Comment: @glennjackman I'd agree to the general advice against using `sudo` in scripts, and in this case I'd motivate it with the fact that the point of the user's code was for the processing to happen non-interactivly. As for `EUID`, I would not turn it into a `bash` script only to use that variable 